# Area inside loop of polar equation, unsolvable problem?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Is this problem solvable?

"Please find the area inside the first loop of the following equation (using polar coordinates): r = cos$(\theta)$ - sec$(\theta)$." 
From what I can tell, this function does not loop at all: 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r+%3D+cos%28%CE%B8%29+-+sec%28%CE%B8%29

Comment: The formula for area in polar coordinates is $$\int \frac12r^2\,\mathrm{d}\theta$$

Comment: I know, but I don't think it loops: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r+%3D+cos%28%CE%B8%29+-+sec%28%CE%B8%29

Comment: It doesn't loop, but the formula will work to get the area swept out between two angles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't loop, and centered at the origin, the area swept out between $\theta=-\frac\pi2$ and $\theta=\frac\pi2$ would be infinite. However, the area swept out between the curve and the asymptote at $x=-1$, would be
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\left[\frac12\sec^2(\theta)-\frac12\left(\cos(\theta)-\sec(\theta)\right)^2\right]\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac12\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\left[2-\cos^2(\theta)\right]\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac12\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\left[2-\frac{1+\cos(2\theta)}2\right]\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac14\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\left[3-\cos(2\theta)\right]\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac{3\pi}4
\end{align}
$$
[image]

---

The implicit equation for this curve is
$$
y^2(1+x)+x^3=0
$$
We can verify the area
$$
\begin{align}
2\int_{-1}^0\sqrt{\frac{-x^3}{1+x}}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=2\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{1-x}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\int_0^1x^{3/2}(1-x)^{-1/2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\[9pt]
&=2\,\mathrm{B}(\tfrac52,\tfrac12)\\[6pt]
&=2\,\frac{\Gamma(\frac52)\Gamma(\frac12)}{\Gamma(3)}\\
&=2\,\frac{\frac34\sqrt\pi\cdot\sqrt\pi}2\\[9pt]
&=\frac{3\pi}4
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I just had a brief follow-up question. If you integrate from 0 to π for r = cos(θ) - sec(θ) using $$\int \frac12r^2\,\mathrm{d}\theta$$ and take the absolute value of the result, you also get 3/4π if I'm not mistaken. Is this by coincidence? Thank you!

Comment: Basically, $$
\begin{align} 
\int_{0}^{\pi}\left[\frac12\left(\cos(\theta)-
\sec(\theta)\right)^2\right]\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
\end{align} =\ -\frac34\pi
$$ is what I found and I was wondering if it's related to the area being swept under the curve.

Comment: @Ninja7777: Something is wrong. You are integrating a positive function and getting a negative value.

Comment: You are right. I redid it and it seems to give 3/4π. Would that mean you can find the area being swept by integrating from 0 to π too (rather than -1/2π to 1/2π, as you proposed)? I think they're equivalent, but I just wanted to run this by you.

Comment: $\sec^2(\theta)$ is not integrable near $\pi/2$. The integral does not converge on $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 2):

I agree there is no loop. Such a curve is a [Cissoid of Diocles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cissoid_of_Diocles).

Comment: (+1) I have never heard of the Cissoid of Diocles before. Thanks for the link!